# scrapy to get Billboard top 200 album names

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Not sure why this scrapy is not getting me any result. Can someone please point to the right direction for me? Im simply trying to scrape album titles from this [page](https://www.billboard.com/charts/year-end/2018/top-billboard-200-albums) .

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class uoc_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "uoc_spider"

    start_urls = [
    "https://www.billboard.com/charts/year-end/2018/top-billboard-200-albums"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.css("chart-details__item-list article"):
            yield {"name_of_album": row.css("div.ye-chart-item__primary-row ::text").extract_first()}

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'})
process.crawl(uoc_spider)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some small modifications in the css selectors seem to work:

```
# add a . to specify it's a class selector
for row in response.css(".chart-details__item-list article"):
  # album title is under class ye-chart-item__title
  yield {"name_of_album": row.css("div.ye-chart-item__title::text").extract_first()}
```